# Material design Parent-child transitions web implementation

Tags: html, css, material-design

Because of first steps in web I can't understand how can I implement [Parent-child transitions](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#hierarchical-transitions)
[image: video]

I need show list of cards and expand the card (with enriched content) when it tapped.

I can't understand which html template and css must be used.